# PandasError:KeyError: "['Brain'] not in index"

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Here's the code :

```
data=pd.read_csv("/home/crpsm/Pycharm/DataSet/headbrain.csv")
print(data.describe())

y=data[["Brain"]]

x=data[["Head"]]
```

when I run this code I got this error:

```
"['Brain'] not in index"
```

Is there any way to fix this error?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: It means there is no column `Brain`, `Head`, what return `print(data.describe())` ?

Comment: @jezrael yes it has a column brain heres the output for describe():             Head        Brain 
count   237.000000   237.000000
mean   3633.991561  1282.873418
std     365.261422   120.340446
min    2720.000000   955.000000
25%    3389.000000  1207.000000
50%    3614.000000  1280.000000
75%    3876.000000  1350.000000
max    4747.000000  1635.000000

Comment: @timgeb sir...can u please tell me if there is any way to fix this error

Comment: @Arjun You should edit the question in order to get the help you want, by which I mean, add the necessary data.

Comment: What is `print(data.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: @jezrael heres the ouput:['Head ', 'Brain ']

Comment: If there is indeed a brain column check if it does not contain any additional characters like spaces and such

Comment: @Arjun yes, remove a space `'Brain '` here

Comment: There are spaces in end of columns names, need `data.columns = data.columns.str.strip()`

Comment: @hellpanderr ooh...thanks it worked..thanks a lot..!!!!

Comment: @jezrael thanks for ur help..it worked!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are spaces in end of columns names, need [`str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) or [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
print(data.columns.tolist())
['Head ', 'Brain ']

data.columns = data.columns.str.rstrip()
```

---

```
data.columns = data.columns.str.strip()
```